how to extract the substates from sdbus-cpp onsignal call
I have put up a demo code to monitor the ssh service signals & to take action when the substate is dead
.SubState                           property  s               "running"                      emits-change
code-
#include <sdbus-c++/sdbus-c++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    const std::string serviceName = "org.freedesktop.systemd1";
    const std::string objectPath = "/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/ssh_2eservice";
    const std::string interfaceName = "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties";
    const std::string signalName = "PropertiesChanged";
    auto sshServiceProxy = sdbus::createProxy(serviceName, objectPath);

    auto Callback_2 = [ ](std::string data){
        std::cout << ": Service state changed for: " << data << std::endl;
    };

    sshServiceProxy->uponSignal(signalName).onInterface(interfaceName).call(Callback_2);
    sshServiceProxy->finishRegistration();

   
    sleep(10);
    return 0;
}

this is compiling & running fine , with data always showing the interface name
If I change the number of parameter the callback is not getting called & if parameter type is changed I am getting compilation erors
I am not able to find any working documenations to get to know the substate value for the ssh service,
Anyone knowing this issues please help
I am expecting to parse the substate value for ssh service

I'm not familiar with sdbus-c++, but the PropertiesChanged signal definitely takes at least three parameters, and I found examples such as this one that seem to make it work.
